# Context.SaveChanges() hanging, seemingly due to nested transactions and FK constraints in Entity Frameworks

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, transactions

I'm confronted with an issue that causes my application to go-out-to-lunch.  I've isolated the situation to involve a trivial update (no impact to keys or indices) on a parent entity, which is wrapped in a TransactionScope and SaveChanges() is run on the context immediately afterwards.  A short while later, child entities related to the updated parent are inserted into a new context instance which is wrapped within an inner TransactionScope.  When SaveChanges() is run for the children, the thread blocks until the SqlCommand.CommandTimeout is reached and the transaction is rolled back.  Below is the code and models.

I've flattened the architecture for presentation here, but the outer transaction is started up by a job manager that processes a queue and spins up a wide variety of classes.  The inner transaction logic actually sits inside a helper class whose intended use is to allow the job classes to make updates which are not rolled back should the outer transaction be undone.

My from-the-hip guess is that the inner SaveChanges() can't complete as the outer SaveChanges() and transaction hasn't been completed.  This puts the parent in an indeterminate state so the constraints can't be validated.  Though, my understanding of System.Transaction and EF is still pretty darn green.

The hope is to avoid an architectural change, or at least keep it super minor.  We're currently running .NET4 and EF5.  Suggestions?  Much thanks in advance.

**Edit:**  Fixed an title ambiguity and added a screen-shot of diagnostic output from SQL.

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Transactions;
using SSI.Server.DataContext;
using SSI.Server.DataModel;

namespace MyBox
{
    class MyBox
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Firing up context...");
            var context = new SsiContext();

            if (!context.parent.Any(p => p.Name == "Mom"))
            {
                context.parent.Add(new parent()
                {
                    Name = "Mom"
                });
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            var tranOpts = new TransactionOptions();
            tranOpts.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
            tranOpts.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);

            using (var outerTran = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, tranOpts))
            {
                var mom = context.parent.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Mom");
                if(mom == null) { throw new InvalidOperationException("Where's momma!?"); }

                Console.WriteLine("Setting parent number and saving in first transaction...");
                mom.Number = 1980;
                context.SaveChanges();

                using (var innerTran = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, tranOpts))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Second transaction create.  Spinning up new context...");
                    var innerContext = new SsiContext();

                    Console.WriteLine("Creating new child, linking to parent, saving, and closing inner transaction...");
                    innerContext.child.Add(new child() { ParentId = mom.ParentId });

                    // Execution hangs here
                    innerContext.SaveChanges();
                    innerTran.Complete();
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Completing outer transaction...");
                outerTran.Complete();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**Parent Model**

```
public class parent
{
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    protected virtual ICollection<child> children { get; set; }
}
```

**Parent Config**

```
public class parentMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<parent>
{
    public parentMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.ParentId);
        this.Property(t => t.ParentId).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(40);
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasMaxLength(20);
        this.Property(t => t.Number);
    }
```

}

**Child Model**

```
public class child
{
    public string ChildId { get; set; }
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    protected virtual parent parent { get; set; }
}
```

**Child Config**

```
public class childMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<child>
{
    public childMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.ChildId);
        this.Property(t => t.ChildId).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(40);
        this.Property(t => t.ParentId).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(40);
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasMaxLength(20);
        this.Property(t => t.Nubmer);
    }
}
```

**SQL SPID Info**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up modifying the architecture by adding an empty virtual method to the base class all job classes derive from.  After a job and the primary transaction complete, we fire off the job's potentially overridden "after-execute" method within a second transaction, allowing jobs a chance to persist data not contingent on the first transaction.

Answer (score 8):

You are experiencing a deadlock.

You have two different database transactions (the inner transaction scope creates a new transaction because of the `RequiresNew` option. Your first transaction is locking some database resource your second transaction needs. The second transaction is blocked by the database, and since the first transaction can't complete until the second one is done, the lock is never released.

SQL server can detect deadlocks, but in this case it can't - it has no way of knowing the first transaction will not complete until the second one is done.